# How to write test case in multiple test file using ginkgo?

Tags: go, ginkgo

How to write test case in multiple test file using ginkgo?

a_suite_test.go file:

```
func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
    RunSpecs(t, "A Suite")
}
```

a_test.go:

```
var _ = Describe("A", func() {
    Context("A", func() {
        It("A", func() {
            Expect(1).To(Equal(1))
        })
    })
})
```

I run `ginkgo`, but error is throwed:

```
Failed to compile A:

go build xxx: no non-test Go files in xxx
```

Can I write test case in other test files rather than writing in suite test file ?

Answer (score 0):

run

```
go test ./...
```

from root of your project, it will run all your tests. With ginkgo you need this suite file, but go test command will grab it and run it.